# Get data from file object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my server side (using Nodejs) I get a request with a file object (req.file). How can I get the data from it and write to another file?

Comment: What is type of the file object?

Comment: This is express that we are talking about (I assume). Perhaps, you should look at this answer first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799033/expressjs-file-upload-check-whether-there-was-indeed-a-file-sent-specify-max-f

Answer (score 0):

First get the readStream of the source file and writeStream of the output file.

Then you can connect the 2 streams with pipe as below.

var fs = require('fs');

var src = fs.createReadStream('in.txt');

var dest = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');

src.pipe(dest);